# Powershell gci -recurse command returning wrong error

Tags: powershell, error-handling, get-childitem

I have two paths stored in variables that I run through the gci command to check access, kind of like this:

```
$p1 = c:\testing\folder1 #path is access denied
$p2 = c:\testing\folder2 #path doesn't exist
```

NOTE: errors are intentional as I'm trying to test my error handling in a script

If I run them through the commands as follows, I'm getting the corresponding errors:

```
gci $p1
error: access denied c:\testing\folder1
gci $p2
error: file doesn't exist c:\testing\folder2
gci -recurse $p1
error: access denied c:\testing\folder1
gci -recurse $p2
error: access denied c:\testing\folder1
```

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

At first I thought it was a problem feeding the path variable into my function, but I've watched the variables and they change appropriately.  The above example is exactly as I tried at a powershell command prompt outside of the script (of course error text is simplified...but you get the gist).

When I run this in my script, and I check the $error output, it's consistent with what I'm finding when I run the commands at the command line.

Powershell version is 4.0 on Windows 7 sp1.

Comment: `$p1 = c:\testing\folder1` should be `$p1 = 'c:\testing\folder1'` otherwise the `c:\testing\folder1: The term 'c:\testing\folder1' is not recognized as the name of a …` error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the -recurse switch to work like you are wanting, it needs to know that folder1 and folder2 are directories.  Set your variables up like this:

```
$p1 = "c:\testing\folder1\" #path is access denied
$p2 = "c:\testing\folder2\" #path doesn't exist
```

and it should return the correct errors.

-recurse is searching in c:\testing when the full path doesn't have the trailing backslash, and it ends up running across folder1, and it gets access denied trying to traverse folder1.

Also the path parameter in the command as follows:

```
PS> gci -path $p1 -recurse
```

Comment: Disagree. The `-recurse` switch works _correctly_ in each case (file or folder): Gets the items in the specified locations and in all child items of the locations.

Comment: I won't argue with you, @JosefZ--it seems to have very odd and inconsistent behavior when the specified path doesn't exist.  If the trailing backslash isn't there and the directory doesn't exist, it seems to search the parent directory, as evidenced by the amount of time it took and the various errors that were returned (while it continued running).

Comment: Exactly. I think it's _correct_ even thought no `File Not Found`-like error  is raised (in contrary to `dir /S`).

Comment: Thanks @TonyHinkle, adding the trailing backslash does exactly what I need it to do.